# ngrx - for loop - take next element once process for current element is completed

Tags: typescript, angular6, ngrx

sorry for sill question. I have a requirement where user has to finish 6 steps to complete 1 activity. If user is clicking on URL of step 6 then I first I have to check whether they have finished previous 5 steps. If not then I have to indicate which steps user has completed and which are pending. For the pending one I am also adding URL so user can easily redirect.

The problem is, I am iterating though each step but because of NG RX it's not waiting for the Action to be completed and moving to the next step. I am not able to identify whether previous steps really finished or not.

I am using NG RX Action, Reducer and Effect technology. Is there anyway I can wait in for loop for first action completion. Once first action completed then and then take second element from the array.

```
// This is part of code in effect file.    
const steps = [Step.Step1, Step.Step2, Step.Step3]

    // It should take next element once evaluation of step1 is completed.
    steps.every((currentStep: Step) => {
                        currentDependentStep = currentStep;
                        switch (currentStep) {
                            case Step.Step1:
                                this.store.dispatch(new fromSomeAction.SomeAction1);
                                this.store.dispatch(new fromSomeAction.SomeAction2);

                                this.store.combineLatest(
                                    this.store.select(fromApp.getData1),
                                    this.store.select(fromApp.getData2)
                                ).first(([payload, data1, data2]) => !!data1 && !!data2)
                                    .subscribe(([payload, data1, data2]) => {
                                        // It should not take second element till I get below result whethere it is completed or not.
                                        isCompleted = <check for some condition>;
                                    });
                                break;
                            case Step.Step2:
                                this.store.dispatch(new fromSomeAction.SomeAction1);
                                this.store.dispatch(new fromSomeAction.SomeAction2);

                                this.store.combineLatest(
                                    this.store.select(fromApp.getData1),
                                    this.store.select(fromApp.getData2)
                                ).first(([payload, data1, data2]) => !!data1 && !!data2)
                                    .subscribe(([payload, data1, data2]) => {
                                        isCompleted = <check for some condition>;
                                    });
                                break;
                            case Step.Step3:
                                this.store.dispatch(new fromSomeAction.SomeAction1);
                                this.store.dispatch(new fromSomeAction.SomeAction2);

                                this.store.combineLatest(
                                    this.store.select(fromApp.getData1),
                                    this.store.select(fromApp.getData2)
                                ).first(([payload, data1, data2]) => !!data1 && !!data2)
                                    .subscribe(([payload, data1, data2]) => {
                                        isCompleted = <check for some condition>;
                                    });
                                break;
                                break;
                            default:
                                isCompleted = false;
                                break;
                        }

                        return !isCompleted;
                    });

                    // Call completed action with payload based on isCompleted
```

Note: Sorry I don't have actual code to share here.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is via router guards, see the [example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/guards/book-exists.guard.ts) for an example.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BookExistsGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private store: Store<fromBooks.State>,
    private googleBooks: GoogleBooksService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  /**
   * This method creates an observable that waits for the `loaded` property
   * of the collection state to turn `true`, emitting one time once loading
   * has finished.
   */
  waitForCollectionToLoad(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(fromBooks.getCollectionLoaded),
      filter(loaded => loaded),
      take(1)
    );
  }

  /**
   * This method checks if a book with the given ID is already registered
   * in the Store
   */
  hasBookInStore(id: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(fromBooks.getBookEntities),
      map(entities => !!entities[id]),
      take(1)
    );
  }

  /**
   * This method loads a book with the given ID from the API and caches
   * it in the store, returning `true` or `false` if it was found.
   */
  hasBookInApi(id: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.googleBooks.retrieveBook(id).pipe(
      map(bookEntity => BookActions.loadBook({ book: bookEntity })),
      tap(action => this.store.dispatch(action)),
      map(book => !!book),
      catchError(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/404']);
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }

  /**
   * `hasBook` composes `hasBookInStore` and `hasBookInApi`. It first checks
   * if the book is in store, and if not it then checks if it is in the
   * API.
   */
  hasBook(id: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.hasBookInStore(id).pipe(
      switchMap(inStore => {
        if (inStore) {
          return of(inStore);
        }

        return this.hasBookInApi(id);
      })
    );
  }

  /**
   * This is the actual method the router will call when our guard is run.
   *
   * Our guard waits for the collection to load, then it checks if we need
   * to request a book from the API or if we already have it in our cache.
   * If it finds it in the cache or in the API, it returns an Observable
   * of `true` and the route is rendered successfully.
   *
   * If it was unable to find it in our cache or in the API, this guard
   * will return an Observable of `false`, causing the router to move
   * on to the next candidate route. In this case, it will move on
   * to the 404 page.
   */
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.waitForCollectionToLoad().pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.hasBook(route.params['id']))
    );
  }
}
```

Todd Motto also has a great post about this topic at [ultimatecourses](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/preloading-ngrx-store-route-guards).